# How to check if a variable is available in the data else use a value provided by user in a R custom function?

Tags: r, function

I have written a custom function with data aurgument like

```
Ploy <- function(data, Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
                 Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", Petal.Length = "Petal.Length"){
  
  Sepal.Length = data[[Sepal.Length]]
  Sepal.Width = data[[Sepal.Width]]
  Petal.Width = data[[Petal.Width]]
  Petal.Length = data[[Petal.Length]]

  #Calculate some derived parameters
  deltak <- (Sepal.Length - Sepal.Width)/390
  ARk <- Petal.Width*2
  
  dat <- cbind.data.frame(deltak, ARk)
  
  #Fitting quadratic model
  mod <- lm(deltak ~ poly(ARk, 2, raw = TRUE))
  
  deltaK0 <- abs(mod$coefficients[[1]])
  
  Ks <- Petal.Length - deltaK0
  
  return(list(`DeltaK0` = deltaK0, `Ks` = Ks))
}
```

It is working fine if all the variables are available in  the data frame like

```
Ploy(Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
     Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", Petal.Length = "Petal.Length", data = iris)
```

Now, if I want to use one numeric value for `Petal.Length` like

```
Ploy(Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
     Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", Petal.Length = 55, data = iris)
```

It returns the following error

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds

Actually, I want to have an option like if the `Petal.Length` is available in the data, then the earlier function should work, else it will utilise the value of `Petal.Length`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to check if the `Petal.Length` argument is a numeric value or a column name.

If numeric value then assign directly to `Petal.Length`.

If a column name then use the provided value.

```
Ploy <- function(data, Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
                 Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", Petal.Length = "Petal.Length") {
  
  Sepal.Length <- data[[Sepal.Length]]
  Sepal.Width <- data[[Sepal.Width]]
  Petal.Width <- data[[Petal.Width]]
  
  if (is.numeric(Petal.Length)) {
    # Use the provided numeric value directly
    Petal.Length <- rep(Petal.Length, nrow(data))
  } else if (is.character(Petal.Length)) {
    # Extract the column values based on the column name
    Petal.Length <- data[[Petal.Length]]
  } else {
    stop("Invalid argument for Petal.Length.")
  }
  
  # Calculate some derived parameters
  deltak <- (Sepal.Length - Sepal.Width) / 390
  ARk <- Petal.Width * 2
  
  dat <- cbind.data.frame(deltak, ARk)
  
  # Fitting quadratic model
  mod <- lm(deltak ~ poly(ARk, 2, raw = TRUE))
  
  deltaK0 <- abs(mod$coefficients[[1]])
  
  Ks <- Petal.Length - deltaK0
  
  return(list(`DeltaK0` = deltaK0, `Ks` = Ks))
}

# Using a column name
Ploy(Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
                Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", Petal.Length = "Petal.Length", 
                data = iris)

# Using a numeric value
Ploy(Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
                Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", Petal.Length = 55, 
                data = iris)
```

Answer (score 3):

If we are checking for all arguments

```
 Ploy <- function(data, Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
                   Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", Petal.Length = "Petal.Length"){
  
   # get the names of the arguments and return its value with mget
   tmpLst <- mget(names(formals()))
   # subset the list without the 'data' component
   tmpLst <- tmpLst[setdiff(names(tmpLst), "data")]
   # create a vector by unlisting
   tmpVec <- unlist(tmpLst)
  # create a logical index by checking whether those are present as
  # columns in the data
  indx <- tmpVec %in% names(data)
    if(any(!indx)) # if there are any not present
    {
 
    # update the columns of data with the value of the corresponding list
    data[names(tmpVec)[!indx]] <- tmpLst[!indx]
   }
  
  # using OP's function from here on...
  Sepal.Length <- data[["Sepal.Length"]]
  Sepal.Width <- data[["Sepal.Width"]]
  Petal.Width <- data[["Petal.Width"]]
  Petal.Length <- data[["Petal.Length"]]

  #Calculate some derived parameters
  deltak <- (Sepal.Length - Sepal.Width)/390
  ARk <- Petal.Width*2
  
  dat <- cbind.data.frame(deltak, ARk)
  
  #Fitting quadratic model
  mod <- lm(deltak ~ poly(ARk, 2, raw = TRUE))
  
  deltaK0 <- abs(mod$coefficients[[1]])
  
  Ks <- Petal.Length - deltaK0
  
  return(list(`DeltaK0` = deltaK0, `Ks` = Ks))
  
  
  
   
   
  }
```

-testing

```
> Ploy(Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
+        Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", Petal.Length = 55, data = iris)
$DeltaK0
[1] 0.002795248

$Ks
 ...

> Ploy(Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
+         Petal.Width = 25, Petal.Length = "Petal.Length", data = iris)
$DeltaK0
[1] 0.00714359

$Ks
  [1] 1.3928564 1.3928564 1.2928564 1.4928564 1.3928564 1.6928564 ..
...

> > Ploy(Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length", Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width", 
+       Petal.Width = "Petal.Width", Petal.Length = "Petal.Length", data = iris)
$DeltaK0
[1] 0.002795248

$Ks
  [1] 1.3972048 1.3972048 1.2972048 1.4972048 1.3972048 1.6972048 1.3972048 1.4972048 1.3972048 1.4972048 1.4972048 1.5972048 1.3972048 1.0972048
 [15] 1.1972048 1.4972048 1.2972048 1.3972048 1.6972048 1.4972048 1.6972048 1.4972048 0.9972048 1.6972048 1.8972048 1.5972048 1.5972048 1.4972048
 [29] 1.3972048 1.5972048 1.5972048 1.4972048 1.4972048 1.3972048 1.497 ...
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what function is doing what for ease of understanding?

Comment: @UseR10085 updated with some comments